# AWS EC2 ubuntu headless selenium send_keys not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium, amazon-ec2, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I wrote a small bot using selenium (python) that is working perfectly in my laptop (ubuntu), both headless and with GUI. Nonetheless, when I try to execute the same code in an AWS EC2 machine with Ubuntu the code does not work. When I use the function to send_keys and then display the text, it is still empty

```
driver.find_element_by_name('email').send_keys('blabla@gmail.com')
driver.find_element_by_name('email').text
```

the options that I am using in the server are:

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36")
```

I use the exact same code in my laptop and it works, same packages, etc

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it just requires explicit wait?

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "email"))).send_keys('blabla@gmail.com')
```

or You can even try with JS as well:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
name = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "email")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', 'blabla@gmail.com')", name)
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: none of those options are working either

Comment: When you say they aren't working, what's the error?

Comment: there are no errors, just when I do driver.find_element_by_name('email').text
it is still empty, while in my laptop it shows the text added